# Python: http.server.ThreadingHTTPServer fails since update to Python 3.12

Tags: python, python-3.x, http.server

I've got a simple Python HTTP server application based on `http.server.ThreadingHTTPServer`, running in a Docker container. It works fine with Python 3.11, but under Python 3.12 aborts with the following as soon as a HTTP request comes in:

```
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50544)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/socketserver.py", line 318, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/socketserver.py", line 706, in process_request
    t.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 971, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't create new thread at interpreter shutdown
```

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:alpine
RUN pip3 install requests psycopg2-binary semantic-version
COPY mysource /
ENTRYPOINT /myprogram.py
```

and the server code in `myprogram.py` is something like

```py
def runServer():
    server = http.server.ThreadingHTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 1234), Server)
    server.serve_forever()

...
thread = threading.Thread(target=runServer)
thread.start()
...
```

Using `HTTPServer` instead of `ThreadingHTTPServer` makes the problem go away.

All worked fine until a few days ago when Python 3.12 came out to which the `python:alpine` image was obviously updated. With `FROM python:3.12-alpine` or `FROM python` (which I suppose is also 3.12) in the Dockerfile it fails, with `FROM python:3.11-alpine` or `FROM: python:3-11` it works.

Did anyone else also observe this? Any idea what to, short of pinning the Python version to 3.11 (which I'm reluctant to do)?

Comment: I noticed the same error with django and is trying to check what is going on.

Comment: Turns out my problem was caused by sentry-sdk: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/issues/2299

Comment: I think this is related to:
https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/115533
I'm getting the same issue in my code with http.server.ThreadingHTTPServer, when I use http.server.HTTPServer instead the error just moved to where I create threads

Comment: FYI - The workaround of adding a sleep to the end of the main thread seems to work for me
https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/113964